# How to set a unique radius for Picasso RoundedCornerTransofrmation()

Tags: android

I have a Recycler view and the view containing n number of url images. The url images are different resolution. I am using Picasso image loader to load the images and set a RoundedCornerTransofrmation() with fixed radius. But different images are setting with different radius.

Comment: I mean the low resolution images, radius are increasing and its visible as a  rounded image. But in high resolution images its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to set fixed radius for different resolution images in Picasso roundedCornerTransformation()

Implement the custom class with implements com.squareup.picasso.Transformation

and modify the transform method as like below

@Override
    public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {

```
    //Get the Image Width Form incoming image
    int radius = source.getWidth();

    //Set the percentage value for radius
    radius = (radius*10)/100;

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(margin, margin, source.getWidth() - margin, source.getHeight() - margin), radius, radius, paint);

    if (source != output) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    return output;
}
```

Based on the percentage value, we can set image curve radius as fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this class in your package :

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;

// enables hardware accelerated rounded corners
// original idea here : http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/
public class RoundedTransformation implements com.squareup.picasso.Transformation {
    private final int radius;
    private final int margin;  // dp

    // radius is corner radii in dp
    // margin is the board in dp
    public RoundedTransformation(final int radius, final int margin) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.margin = margin;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(margin, margin, source.getWidth() - margin, source.getHeight() - margin), radius, radius, paint);

        if (source != output) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "rounded";
    }
```

you can use above class like this :

```
Picasso.with(c).load(s[0]).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).transform(new RoundedTransformation(40,4)).error(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder)).into(holder.im);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I had done the same thing. But how we can set the variable radius in low resolution image and high resolution image dynamically. My problem here is the image curve is increasing for low resolution images and decreasing for high resolution images. Is it possible to set the radius based on the image resolution dynamically?.

Comment: @Nithinjith, radius is render same for both low and high resolution images it is not possible to render different radius for low and high resolution images.